# How can I concat these two rows in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I have the following data in a single table:

[image]

I need a SQL query that can combine the data to append url1 to the batch row and url2 to the single row. Could I use the KNO column to create some sort of matching information?

Result:

[image]

Comment: You need a column that binds together rows. Do you have such column?

Comment: can we assume KNO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution using `INNER JOIN`. I modified the `kno` column of the "applyPages" Rows to contain the corresponding process name, then I joined them on that column:

```sql
SELECT kname, kno, kvalue, url 
    FROM (SELECT kname, kvalue FROM mytable WHERE kname='ProcessName%') A 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT kname,url, kno FROM mytable WHERE kname='ApplyPage') B 
    ON A.kname = B.kno
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation. Assuming, as commented by you, that `kno` defines the groups of rows, you can do:

```
select 
    kno,
    max(case when kname = 'ProcessName' then kvalue end) kvalue,
    max(case when kname = 'ApplyPage' then kvalue end) url
from mytable
group by kno
```

This does not output `'ProcessName`' in the first column because that would be a fixed value anyway.

Comment: if process name were different values, how would this query change?

Comment: @JoshSharkey: you would just change the filters in the conditional `max()`s.

Comment: Sorry, can you help my by updating the answer?

Comment: @JoshSharkey: something like... `select 
    kno,
 max(case when kname like 'ProcessName%' then kname end) kvalue,
    max(case when kname like 'ProcessName%' then kvalue end) kvalue,
    max(case when kname = 'ApplyPage' then kvalue end) url
from mytable
group by kno`

Answer (score 0):

Does aggregation do what you want?

```
select kname, kno, min(kvalue), max(kvalue)
from t
group by kname, kno;
```